# How send send wild characters on http post request

Tags: http, post, request, wildcard

I'm trying to send a file using an http post request that has the %20 escape character in the name eg: file%20name.txt.

The problem is that once is uploaded the file name is 'file name.txt' not 'file%20name.txt'.

Is it possible to escape the % somehow???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrap it in `urlencode()` again. (Though you might want to reconsider if encoded literal filenames is the way to go. That sometimes means more effort down the lane.)

Comment: That was it, Thanks Mario.